# Crontab runs but doesn't execute

Tags: bash, cron, crontab

My crontab looks like this

```
* * * * * /opt/PPP/update_playlists.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /opt/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

(I set to every minute for testing purposes)

The duckdns script runs fine. My update_playlists.sh script seems to run according to /var/log/syslog

```
Jan  8 21:18:01 eucalyptus CRON[2738]: (callum) CMD (/opt/PPP/update_playlists.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1)
Jan  8 21:18:01 eucalyptus CRON[2737]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But /var/log/cron.log is blank, and the command does not execute.

Running

```
bash /opt/PPP/update_playlists.sh
```

works fine. update_playlists.sh just runs other scripts. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 system `/var/log` does not have other-write permission (`drwxrwxr-x 25 root syslog 4096 2019-01-08 15:04:44.563105393 +0000 /var/log/`), so I would not expect `cron.log` to be created there, unless run from `root`.

Comment: Ah this was my issue - I'm now closer to solving why it wasn't working thanks!